# jQuery - apply function to multiple select elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, select, multiple-instances

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    </script>
    <title>
      Select
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var MyArray = {
        "Windows": "imgx.jpg",
        "Linux": "imgt.jpg",
        "Mac": "imgi.jpg",
        "MS DOS": "imgy.jpg",
        "1GB": "imggb.jpg"
      }

      jQuery(function() {

        jQuery('.product').change(function() {

          var xkey = MyArray[jQuery.trim(jQuery(".product option:selected").text())];

          if (typeof xkey == 'string') {

            alert(xkey);

          }

        });


      });
    </script>
    <div>
      <select name="options_random_nr_yy" class="product">
        <option value="">
          -- Select --
        </option>
        <option value="56">
          1GB
        </option>
        <option value="57">
          2GB
        </option>
        <option value="73">
          4GB
        </option>
        <option value="209">
          8GB
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="options_random_nr_xx" class="product">
        <option value="">
          -- Select --
        </option>
        <option value="63">
          Windows
        </option>
        <option value="65">
          Linux
        </option>
        <option value="67">
          Mac
        </option>
        <option value="89">
          MS DOS
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The problem is that it always return "undefined" when I select an option. However, if I remove one of the `<select>` elements, it works fine!

How can I apply the same function to all `<select>` elements with same class name (in this example the common class is "product")?

Comment: Instead of `jQuery(".product option:selected").text()`, use `$(this).find("option:selected").text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that jQuery('.product') returns a list of all of the selects, rather then the one that is currently selected. Most modern browsers handle the conversion from list of one DomElement to a particular DomElement (thus if you remove one it suddenly works), however, within event handlers, you can use $(this) to work for one option in old browsers and for multiple items in all browsers.

($ is shorthand for jQuery)

So what you want to do is:

```
 $(function(){
      $('.product').change(function(){
          var xkey = MyArray[$.trim($(this).find("option:selected").text())];
      }
      if (typeof xkey == 'string') {

        alert(xkey);

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var xkey = MyArray[jQuery.trim(jQuery(".product option:selected").text())];
```

try

```
var xkey = MyArray[jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val())];
```

in event handlers this always points to an element where even happened.

**UPD**:

I see your MyArray have option text instead option value as a key, so you should use:

```
var xkey = MyArray[jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").text())];
```

Comment: He wants the text, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your event to each element. Search the array with [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). Clean solution:

```
 jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('.product').change(function() {

        var xkey = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text())

        if(jQuery.inArray(xkey, MyArray) && typeof xkey == 'string')
            alert(xkey);
    })
 });
```

Comment: .each is not needed at all here.  `$('.product').change(function(){})` will already attach event handler to all `.product`

Comment: I've optimized it a little bit

Answer (score 1):

Do this way using `.each()`:-

```
var MyArray = {
        "Windows": "imgx.jpg",
        "Linux": "imgt.jpg",
        "Mac": "imgi.jpg",
        "MS DOS": "imgy.jpg",
        "1GB": "imggb.jpg"
      };
jQuery('.product').change(function() {
  jQuery(".product option:selected").each(function() {
    var xkey = MyArray[jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text())];
    if (typeof xkey == 'string') {
      alert(xkey);
    }
  });
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Tr2hb/)**

Other way of doing this using `.map()`

```
jQuery('.product').change(function() {
  $(".product option:selected").map(function(){
        var xkey = MyArray[jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text())];
        if (typeof xkey == 'string') {
        alert(xkey);
        }
    });
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO - Using map()](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Tr2hb/1/)**